# How to write Or method in my mongodb filter using .net MongoDB drive

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

As I am new to MongoDB I spend much time in writing collection filters in my .netcore 5 project.
currently I filtering the collection using REGEX method.
now I need to check two fields with OR condition.Like below,

```
{$or :[{ Code: { $regex: "dxb", $options: 'i' } },{ Name.Content: { $regex: "dxb", $options: 'i' }}]}
```

So I want to know How to write OR method filter.
Following shows my REGEX filter code.
{"Name.Content": { $regex: "dub", $options: 'i' }}

```
terminalsCollection = await _terminalsCollection
        .Find(Builders<TerminalDocument>.Filter.Regex(e => e.Name.Content, new BsonRegularExpression(keyword, "i")))
        .Project<TerminalDocument>(terminalFeilds)
        .Limit(15)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var orTerminalsFilter = Builders<TerminalDocument>.Filter.Or(
            Builders<TerminalDocument>.Filter.Regex(e => e.Name.Content, new BsonRegularExpression(keyword, "i")),
            Builders<TerminalDocument>.Filter.Regex(e => e.Code, new BsonRegularExpression(keyword, "i")));

        terminalsCollection = await _terminalsCollection
        .Find(orTerminalsFilter)
        .Project<TerminalDocument>(terminalFeilds)
        .Limit(10)
        .ToListAsync();
```

I have found solution,we have to define the filters[].
Here `Builders<TerminalDocument>.Filter.Regex(e => e.Name.Content, new BsonRegularExpression(keyword, "i"))` is a one filter definition, like wise we can define the filters, and pass to Or Method as params.